# Select a UUID

Tags: uuid

We need to generate UUIDs for every single entry we store in the
backend. As I read in Wikipedia: Uuid Java implementation, there are 3 available UUID
generators:

```
- Standard Java UUID generator(which only support version 3 and 4)
- JUG  which support all the version but 2
- UUID  which only support version 1 (MAC address based)
```

Please advise on which generator we should use, assuming
the licenses are compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3 will not solve your problem of generating *fresh* UUID for each entry.  If you have no other requirements (security for example) Version 1 is usually enough.

If you want to hide every possible information (MAC address and time of generation) use Version 4.

Answer (score 1):

The UUID generator used by Windows is a Version 4 generator by default.

The standard Java generator using v4 UUIDs would work just fine.